# Определить отсутствие консоли и создать оную если ее нет

Tags: winapi, delphi, консоль

Есть приложение, которое(изначально неизвестно) ни формы ни консоли может не быть изначально как и оба могут уже присутствовать(и консоль и форма).

Как определить отсутствие консоли и создать оную если ее нет?

Answer (score 1):

Cоздать консоль можно только если ее нет, так что можно просто вызывать AllocConsole без всяких условий. [Пруф](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console.

А вообще, для проверки наличия консоли можно использовать например [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Добавлю только функцию FreeConsole, которая удаляет созданное консольное окно.

И ещё, один очень важный момент. Если в консоли ожидать ввод (например, с помощью readln), то главный тред будет на паузе. Поэтому не удивляйтесь, что при ожидании ввода, форма может не обновлятся.

Answer (score -1):

В любом случае или это консоль или GUI. Определяется компилятором на стадии сборки. Смотрите структуру PE файлов.

Технически проще консоль спрятать, запустить цикл форм. В Delphi такое довольно просто в реализации.

Comment: Неподходит..
Давайте так.. есть команда установить хэндл дефолтного вывода...
вопрос тогда в том как создать окно такого же класса как и консольное)

Comment: У CnPack есть CnVCL среди прочего есть компонент CnConsole(как-то так), там показана реализация консоли, если вы её не хотите компилировать.